# ListPlot with Opacity strange outcome

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.3.**

---

Simply do this

```
ListPlot[Range[1500], PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.02], Opacity[0.5, Black]}}, 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

we obtain

[image]

What's wrong with this darker segments each 500 point?

Comment: I do not see this problem on macOS with Mathematica 12.3.1. It may be a platform-specific rendering issue. Please indicate your OS and Mathematica version. You might try using fewer plot points and see if it helps. It looks like there are more points than the width of the image in pixels. Try `MaxPlotPoints`.

Comment: If you assign the graphics to the variable `g`, what does `Count[g, _Line, Infinity]` return? For me it returns 1. If for you it returns a greater number, it may be the (correctable) root cause of the issue.

Comment: No such problem on  Linux or Windows 11 with Mathematica 12.3.1.

Comment: Indeed, this bug is fixed after ver. 12.3

Comment: @Szabolcs On my laptop (Windows 11, Mma 13.0.1.0) this is working fine, but a colleage is running into the same problem with a newer version of Mma (Mac OS, Mma 13.3.0.0). Could you / anyone check this to see if this bug has been reintroduced?

Comment: @JulesLamers Confirmed with 13.3.1 on macOS. Can't test with earlier versions at the moment.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've reported this to Mma; they replied "[...] This bug was fixed for more recent versions of Mathematica. In particular, this bug is not present in 13.1.0 and 13.2.0, nor is it in the most recent version: 13.3.1." Does that match your observation?

Comment: @JulesLamers No, I'll report it as well.

Comment: I see this in every version _except_ 12.3. Note that this is likely macOS-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce this using Mathematica 12.2 on macOS, but not using Mathematica 12.3.1. I believe it is a rendering bug.

[image]

Simply copying the graphics expression between a 12.3 and a 12.2 notebook makes the problem appear/disappear, which shows that the issue is specific to graphics rendering.

---

It seems that the problem appears whenever there is a `Line` with a large number of points, and `Opacity` of less than 1. Perhaps the line is broken to smaller pieces internally and what we see if the overlap between these pieces?

A simpler example to reproduce the problem is:

```
Graphics[{Thickness[0.02], GrayLevel[0, 0.5], 
  Line[Table[{k, k}, {k, 1000}]]}]
```

---

One possible workaround is to reduce the number of points. Unfortunately, there is a risk that the plot quality will be reduces as well. I suggest that you experiment with [`MaxPlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html) settings. I need to use `MaxPlotPoints -> 100` or less on my machine to make the problem go away, showing that the `Line` is broken to pieces with 100 points each. It looks like on your machine this value may be closed to 500 (as I see three overlaps for 1500 points). 500 should be sufficient for most plots.

---

I expect someone might be able to produce a workaround using undocumented `Graphics` rendering options. I suggest you contact Wolfram Support and if they give you a better workaround, post it here.

Comment: Wolfram Technical Support got back to me with a workaround, see below

Answer (score 1):

This bug for MacOS seems to have persisted in all recent versions except for 12.3.1 (cf the comments to the OP). I've reported it to Mma. For now they advise a way around the problem that does indeed seem to work:

> In the meantime, there is a workaround that you can try or suggest to
> your colleagues working on macOS. Please include the
> `CapForm["Butt"]` to the PlotStyle option:
>
> `ListPlot[Range[1500], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {{CapForm["Butt"],Thickness[0.02], Opacity[0.5, Black]}}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True]`